# set new column of values to list of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I want add an identifier column to a list of data.frames (before unlisting them). I tried using `lapply`:

```
names = c('a', 'b')
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(x) my.list[[x]]$names = names[[x]])
```

But this returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"
```

Instead of:

```
[[1]]
  y1 y2 names
1  1  4    a
2  2  5    a
3  3  6    a

[[2]]
  y1 y2  names
1  3  6      b
2  2  5      b
3  1  4      b
```

edit: I had been using `index(my.list)` (from `zoo`). Edited to `seq_along(my.list)` to stay in base R

Comment: `index` is not a base R function. Please include the names of any packages that you are using. (`seq_along(my.list)` is sufficient).

Comment: fwiw, both `dplyr::bind_rows` and `data.table::rbindlist` have the ability to automatically add an id column using the names from the list.

Comment: you need to return the altered data.frame. `lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(x) {my.list[[x]]$names = names[[x]]; my.list[[x]]})` will work. Also, `lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(x) transform(my.list[[x]], names = names[[x]]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` to process two sequences in parallel (add names to a list of data frames):

```
Map(function(df, name) transform(df, names=name), my.list, names)

#[[1]]
#  y1 y2 names
#1  1  4     a
#2  2  5     a
#3  3  6     a

#[[2]]
#  y1 y2 names
#1  3  6     b
#2  2  5     b
#3  1  4     b
```